# Is there an algorithm to "guess" a suitable $\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I'm reading Henle/Kleinenberg's *Infinitesimal Calculus*. Here:

[image]

They speak about *guessing* a $\delta$. Is there an algorithm to find a suitable $\delta$?

Comment: Not really. $\qquad$

Comment: There is no algorithm to guess a suitable $ \delta $ and  suspect if there was you could use that algorithm as a halting oracle.

Answer (score 2):

As @ZacharySelk comments, "not really". The author is telling a joke - perhaps one only mathematicians would appreciate. You work the algebra out on scratch paper, figure out what $\delta$ you need to get the $\epsilon$ inequality you want, then write the proof starting with that miraculously useful guess.

This was a particularly easy example. With practice you get better at guessing in hard cases.

Comment: But why there couldn't exist such an algorithm?

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle  There might be one for some very simple classes of problems, but the  general occasions on which you must find a $\delta$ don't share enough structure to build an algorithm on. So you need to practice actual thinking on the easy examples. And sometimes there is no $\delta$ and that's what you want to prove.

Comment: What is "having structure to build an algorithm"?

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle You need to be able to describe the problem in a language formal enough to specify a solution. For example, you could write an algorithm to find $\delta$ if all you wanted to do was to prove that quadratic functions are continuous.